# What causes updateUIView() to be called in this code?

Tags: swiftui, combine

I understand that the change of the @State variable notifies the @Binding that the state has changed but what then causes the updateUIView() method to be called? There is obviously some hidden connection between the @Binding and the call, but how does that work?

```
//  Experiment_Map_View.swift

import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct Experiment_Map_View: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var test: Bool

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        print("updateUIView")
        print(test)
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    final class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var control: Experiment_Map_View

        init(_ control: Experiment_Map_View) {
            print("init -----------------")
            self.control = control
        }

    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
         print("makeUIView")
        let map = MKMapView()
        map.delegate = context.coordinator
        return map
    }
}

struct MyRootView: View {
    @State var test: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Experiment_Map_View(test: $test)
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Button("Next") {
                    print("Next")
                    self.test.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

struct Experiment_Map_View_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyRootView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`SwiftUI` is managing the memory of `@State` and `@Binding` objects and automatically refreshes any UI of any `View`s that rely on your variable. `SwiftUI` is closed source so unfortunately we don’t know exactly how this is done yet, but for simplicity it could be thought of as a behind the scenes `didSet` modifier.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out that much. I was hoping someone knew how this is really accomplished "behind the scenes".

Comment: That’s proprietary Apple knowledge at the moment. The correct answer is that the answer is not yet public because the source code is not yet public.

Comment: @LotteTortorella do you know the answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59430099/pencilkit-in-swiftui